# I Deleted All Environment Variables and system variables

Tags: window

how to fix this error

i deleted all environment variables and systems variables
what i do now how to fix this

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may have to reinstall Windows on it.

Comment: Boot into WinPE and load the registry hive so you can modify and restore the original PATH variable contained within `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`.  Of course, you should be able to manually navigate to the directory that contains `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe`

Comment: @Ramhound You should make that an answer. I do not see another way to fix this either.

Comment: @AnjhaDish - No; There is no other way. At this point since your asking me questions in a language I don’t understand I won’t help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a commandprompt as administrator

Type in the following:

```
set path=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
set windir=C:\Windows
set SystemDrive=C:
set SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
set ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
set ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
set ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
set ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files

setx PATH "%PATH%"
setx windir "%windir%"
setx SystemDrive "%SystemDrive%"
setx SystemRoot "%SystemRoot%"
setx ProgramData "%ProgramData%"
setx ProgramFiles "%ProgramFiles"
setx ProgramFiles(x86) "%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
setx ProgramW6432 "%ProgramW6432%"
```

Comment: my command prompt can't open as administrator how to fix this system

Comment: Can you open explorer, then manually navigate to C:\Windows\System32, find cmd.exe there, and right-click run as Administrator? If that doesn't work, can you start Task Scheduler using the shortcut from your start menu? (search there)

Comment: Also, you can try these: https://www.shellhacks.com/set-environment-variable-without-admin-rights-windows/

Comment: @AnjhaDish - So navigate to the directory that contains PowerShell executable or  cmd.exe.  This problem can be solved without reinstalling Windows.

Comment: It should, yes. If for some reason you still can't run cmd as administrator from explorer, I know another way using TaskScheduler by saving the above as a file.cmd and then running it as SYSTEM user.

Comment: cant open cmd as administrator

Comment: Can you start TaskScheduler then? Also, try running the above without administrator and see if that works. It may be enough to allow you to open a cmd as admin and repeat it.

Comment: thank you to all i solve my problems thanks

Comment: How did you solve it? If one of the answers here was the solution, could you mark that answer as solved? If not but one of the answers was closest to what you did, mark that one as solved. If solved in a completely different way, can you post an answer of your own and accept that one? This will allow others to learn from it and also tell people you no longer need help.

Answer (score 0):

If System Restore is enabled, rollback to a time before this was done.

You get to System Restore via
*Start > Create a restore point* and clicking the "System Restore"
button. If you see any checkpoints, verify their date.

If your PATH is not working, here's the full path of the program :
`C:\Windows\System32\SystemPropertiesProtection.exe`.

Comment: when i click system restore point this error show me, %windir%\system32\systempropertiesproction.exe                           window cannot find %windir%\system32\systempropertiesproction.exe. make sure you type the name correctly and then try again

Comment: You have deleted the `windir` environment variable. So use the full path as at the end of my answer in CMD or via the key combination Win+R.

Comment: can't work this method

Comment: You mean that the program doesn't work, or that you have no checkpoints ?

Comment: thank you buddy i solved

Answer (score -1):

If you still can than try to create a new profile and using it or import data from it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1231178)

Comment: @Dominique Why not improve the answer a bit instead? [Here are instructions on how to create a new Windows user](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-or-remove-accounts-on-your-pc-104dc19f-6430-4b49-6a2b-e4dbd1dcdf32#WindowsVersion=Windows_10)

Comment: this system can't make to do new user

Comment: @Gantendo Why bother? A new user will not bring back the _system_ environment variables. This answer unfortunately cannot solve the problem.

Comment: thanks bro my problem solved